# How do you use SecKeychainGetPath in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to call the OS X Security method `SecKeychainGetPath` in Swift. This is what I have so far:

```
var pLength = 1024 as UInt32
var pName = malloc(1024)
let oStatus = SecKeychainGetPath(chain, &pLength, &pName)
```

The method definition of `SecKeychainGetPath` is:

```
func SecKeychainGetPath(keychain: SecKeychain!, ioPathLength: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>, pathName: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>) -> OSStatus
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Cannot invoke 'SecKeychainGetPath' with an argument list of type '(SecKeychain, inout UInt32, inout UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)'
```

I believe that my `chain` parameter is fine but I think it's the `pName` parameter that the compiler is complaining about. `malloc` returns a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` where `SecKeychainGetPath` expects `pName` to be a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`. I've tried casting but that marked as unsafe and unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass any pointer to a function expecting an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`, but you need to pass a matching pointer when the type is expected. In this case you need an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`:

```
var pLength = 1024 as UInt32
var pName = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.alloc(1024)
let oStatus = SecKeychainGetPath(chain, &pLength, pName)
```

Note also that `UnsafeMutablePointer` instances don't need the `&` prefix in the function call.

Alternately, you can construct an array instead of an `UnsafeMutablePointer`, and pass that as an `inout` parameter:

```
var pName = Array(count: 1024, repeatedValue: 0 as Int8)
var pLength = UInt32(pName.count)
let oStatus = SecKeychainGetPath(chain, &pLength, &pName)
```

The benefit for this alternate approach is that Swift is handling all memory-manangement for you—no need to `dealloc` the pointer later.

Comment: Correct, thanks. Also the next logical piece is to read the returned pName as `let path = NSFileManager.defaultManager().stringWithFileSystemRepresentation(pName, length: Int(pLength))`